# Changing the value of a variable from getch()

Tags: python, msvcrt, getch

**Update: I've added the parentheses and byte however the code still doesn't change the output.**

I'm trying to write a python program that sees what the user is typing using getch() and then changes it (and prints the changed version) - so if the user types '1', 'one' would be printed for example.

Here's my code:

```
import msvcrt as m
character = m.getch
while True:
    if m.getch == b'1':
        print 'one'
        break
```

This just prints what the user types.

Please help me get the program to change the variable correctly.

Comment: I can't test this (not on Windows) but it looks like you are assigning the **function** `m.getch` to `character`. Call it instead: `character = m.getch()` -- then what is its value? (You can always `print character` or be fancy and insert `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` below it to see what the value of it is during execution.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, I have created the code snippet below to fulfill your requirements

> if the user types '1', 'one' would be printed

For demo I did some more stuff like if user presses `2` then `'Two'` will be displayed and if the user presses any other key, it will be displayed by default.

**Code**:

```
import msvcrt as m
character = m.getch()
while True:
    if character == '1':
        print 'one'
        break
    elif character =='2':
        print 'Two'
        break
    else:
        print character
        break
```